# OrientDB vs Neo4j, simple stress test

Tags: neo4j, orientdb, stress-testing

I'm posting because I'm having strange results while stressing Neo4j 2.2.7 and OrientDB 2.1.4 and I am looking for an explanation (I'm pretty sure there is no bug in the code but if anyone is interested I'd be happy to share it).
Here are the facts:

1. I'm continuously shooting to the DBs the following OSql and Cypher queries, which are equivalent (except for the name of the attributes)

   - `SELECT both('Meets').email FROM Employee WHERE nt_account = '<employeeid>'`
   - `MATCH (e: Employee {Nt_Account: '<employeeid>'}) -[:MEETS]- (y: Employee) RETURN y.E_Mail`
2. `nt_account` and `Nt_Account` are both indexed.
3. the execution time of the queries, averaged over 100 repetitions, is:

   - OrientDB: 4.4ms
   - Neo4j: 7.6ms
4. to parallelise execution I'm using AKKA actors
5. Despite of the previous points, when continuously shooting the above mentioned queries from just one thread, I measured that Neo4j can serve ~59k requests, while OrientDB can serve ~16k requests.
6. The number of requests OrientDB could serve is consistently 3 to 5 times lower than Neo4j.

As you can imagine, points 5. and 6. shocked me a bit as I was expecting the number of requests served by OrientDB to be the greatest, given that it can execute the query in almost half of the time.

Does anybody have any idea of what's going on? 
Is OrientDB doing something after having returned the query result?
Am I using the API unproperly?

---

**More detail:**

Here is how I execute the query in OrientDB (I found this [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html)):

```
val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
graph.command(new OCommandSQL(<the_query>)).execute()
val ellapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
```

`graph` is an `OrientGraphNoTx` instance, there is one such instance per actor. 
I got comparable results by using the `OrientGraph` and a number of requests slightly lower by using the REST API.

Here is the method I used to execute the Neo4j query (notice that I turned off JSON streaming):

```
def queryRest(query: String): Unit = {
  val reqData = s"""{"statements" : [ { "statement" : "$query" } ] }"""
  val response = Http("http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit")
    .postData(reqData)
    .header("content-type", "application/json")
    .header("accept", "application/json;stream=false")
    .asString.body.length
}
```

Here are the measurements (the last row of both tables does not make much sense as the effective level of parallelism I achieved, `computation_time / 1minute`, is only ~12).
[image: my results]

Comment: how did you get the results of point 3?

Comment: Hi @wolf4ood. I used the same settings as in the stress test: `OrientGraphNoTx` for Orient and REST API for Neo4j (the same code I've reported). I executed the query 100 times and averaged the execution time I've measured. In some repetition Neo4j has spikes of 30 ms, that's why the overall average is a bit higher. I can share with you the data if you're interested ;)

Comment: Can you post your code on github? Maybe a reduced version, with instructions to reproduce your test env.

Comment: How do you manage connections? One OrientGraph instance per thread?

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments and sorry for the belated answer: I was afk during the week end. [Here](https://github.com/albertotonon/neo4j_orient_Stress) is a repo containing the parts of the code I wrote that are referenced in the post. Unfortunately I cannot share the data, however I've included a file defining the OrientDB schema (`schema_definition.sql`).

Comment: @Lvca: yes, each actor has its own OrientGraph instance. Cfr. the `RemoteRequester` class https://github.com/albertotonon/neo4j_orient_Stress/blob/master/src/main/scala/stresstest/OrientStressTest.scala

Comment: take a look at [Graph Factory](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Graph-Factory.html) as it is the recommended way to obtain instances for the graphs. It might be that creating the instances using the normal graph constructor can add some overhead.